# $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed map, $f^{-1}(\{ y\}) $ is compact $\forall y\in Y$ then $X$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, $Y$ is compact and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed map (meaning that $f(A) $ is closed for any closed subset $A$ of $X$) such that $f^{-1} (\{ y\}) =\{x\in X, f(x) =y\} $ is compact $\forall y\in Y$ then $X$ is compact.
How do I prove this?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Counterexample: the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$. You need more conditions to prove it.

Comment: @Hanul yes sorry, I forgot to say that $Y$ is compact as well.

Comment: Please edit your question.